# Xamarin SOAP Web Service

Tags: web-services, soap, xamarin, xamarin.mac

I created a Portable Library Project in Xamarin. I want to add web service but the framework area is closed. What is the reason for this? Is there anyone who has experienced the same problem ?

Exp Url : 111.111.11.11:8013/Services/Kurum/IdentityMngmnt/Authentication_V1?wsdl

[Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SXLwa.png)
[Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kwo5I.png)

Comment: That didn´t even exists in older versions so I guess the SOAP option is not yet developed. Did you try adding the web reference with Visual Studio and then checking if it works in Xamarin Studio?

Comment: As you said, I tried Windows with Visual Studio. I chose Profile 44 and ran it. I applied it to Mac OS, but it did not work.
Why Mac OS does not work (with Macos Sierra Xamarin Studio)
Thanks

Comment: what did not work? what are the errors?

Comment: Might help to look over the Xamarin guides for web services: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/web_services/#Windows_Communication_Foundation_WCF and https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/web_services/walkthrough_working_with_WCF/   I know in the past you had to generate the proxy on Windows with the SLSvcUtil tool as indicated in the second link. This is because (from the 1st link) "In general, the Xamarin platform supports the same client-side subset of WCF that ships with the Silverlight runtime. ..."

Comment: I understand, why does not mac os xamarin work in studio studio?Does not work xamarin(macOS) studio but work a visual studio (Windows).

Thanks